# How to change a single value of checkbox inside a localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm trying to change a value inside localstorage. This item is the status of a checkbox. I want, everytime that a checkbox is checked to set the value to true or false of that checkbox. I tried many ways until I realized that there is no way you can change a value without using JSON.

To add the value I use:

```
localStorage.setItem("status-" + i, $status.is(":checked"));
```

and to delete I use:

```
var parentId = $this.parent().attr('id');
localStorage.removeItem("'" + parentId + "'");
```

Now to change the value I tried:

```
$itemList.delegate("#status-" + i, 'click', function(e) {

                var $this = $(this);
                var parentId = this.parent().attr('id');            

                if ($this.is(":checked")) { 

                    localStorage.setItem("'" + parentId + "'".val("fdgsdagf"));
                    // Note that alert here works.

                }
});
```

This is how my local storage looks like:
[image]
I hope someone could help me. I've been working on it for few days...
Here is a fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/CC5Vw/7/

Thanks alot

Comment: From what I've tested, setting the value works all right, the problem is somewhere else... Check it here http://jsfiddle.net/CC5Vw/7/show/ there should be console.log every iteration saying the values of i,j and k variables. It runs just once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/Rh4Au/6/ works well..

### changes http://jsfiddle.net/CC5Vw/7/ to http://jsfiddle.net/Rh4Au/6/

---

line 30:

`+ "<div class='checkbox'><input type='checkbox' class='test' id='status-" +` **`i`** `+ "'></div>"`
`i` chaged to `j` because i is the length and j is the iterator.

---

insertion after line 34:

```
    var tempasd = orderList[j].split("-")[1];
    if(localStorage.getItem("status-"+tempasd) == "true") {
        $("#status-"+j).get(0).checked = true
    }
    else {
        $("#status-"+j).get(0).checked = false
    }
}
```

The code loads the data from `localStorage` and check in the checked checkboxes.
The `tempasd` is a temporary variable store the current ID num of the checkbox (because they not always come ascending.

---

changes from line 99 to 117:

```
// ON STATUS CLICK   
console.log('i=',i,' j=',j, 'k=',k);


$itemList.delegate("#status-" + i, 'click', function(e) {  // ON CLICK
    var $this = $(this);
    var parentId = $this.attr('id');    
       
    if ($this.is(":checked")) {


        console.log('set ', parentId, 'to foo');
        localStorage.setItem(parentId, 'foo');
    //            localStorage.setItem("'" + parentId + "'".val("fdgsdagf"));
    //            localStorage.setItem($this.parent().attr('checked', true)); 
    //            window.location = "http://mail.aol.com"
    }

});
```

to

```
// ON STATUS CLICK   
console.log('i=',i,' j=',j, 'k=',k);
var tempxx;
for(tempxx = 0;tempxx < j; tempxx++) {
$itemList.delegate("#status-" + tempxx, 'click', function(e) {  // ON CLICK
    var $this = $(this);
    var parentId = $this.parent().parent().attr('id').split("-")[1];   


    

        console.log('set ', parentId, 'to foo');
        localStorage.setItem("status-"+parentId, $this.is(":checked"));
//            localStorage.setItem("'" + parentId + "'".val("fdgsdagf"));
//            localStorage.setItem($this.parent().attr('checked', true)); 
//            window.location = "http://mail.aol.com"

   
});

}
```

i need the loop because it needs to delegate an event to each checkbox, and also the event must set the `localStorage` to `false` when it gets unchecked.

btw the `.parent().parent()` is unnecesarry now because i fixed at line 30.

Comment: How can I thank you sir. There seems to be a small problem with the ordering though. If you change the order and select a box. I'll try and sort out the problem. Thanks again

Comment: bug fixed. || there is a bug again. trying to fix. || fixed.

Comment: I don't know what to say really. Thanks alot. I've been trying to fix this problem for ages.

Comment: You should include a synopsis with code that demonstrates how you fixed the problem, not just link to an external site that "works".